# Difference in use of rounded rectangle and normal rectangle

Tags: model, diagram, uml

In any diagram be a uml or any software engineering model diagram whats the difference in using a rounded rectangle and a rectangle.?
----Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For UML specifically, rectangles are generally used for structural concepts: classes, objects, packages.  Rounded rectangles are used for behavioural concepts: states, activities.

There's no "universal" software engineering convention I'm aware of.